# Javascript: Image button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript Quiz and I would like to make an image appear when the user clicks a button. For example: when they click the correct answer a green thubs up appears. here is my code at the moment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Task 1</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 55px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    .tasks {
      color: black;
      font-size: 250%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .t&f {
      color: white;
      font-size: 250%;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index_page.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task1.html">Task 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task2.html">Task 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task3.html">Task 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task4.html">Task 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task5.html">Task 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task6.html">Task 6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="task7.html">Task 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="script-1.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script>
  </script>
  <div class='tasks'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h1>Task 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tasks'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h3>True or False Quiz</h3>
      <h5>Question One</h5>
      <h6>1) Michael Jackson’s Thriller is the greatest-selling album of
            all time.</h6>
      <button onclick="document.bgColor='Green'; alert('Correct! Good job :)')">True</button>
      <button onclick="document.bgColor='Red'; alert('Wrong! Unlucky. Try again :(')">False</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tasks'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h5>Question Two</h5>
      <h6>2) The modern Caesar salad is derived from a recipe dating back
            to ancient Rome.</h6>
      <button onclick="document.bgColor='Red';alert('Wrong! Unlucky. Try again :(')">True</button>
      <button onclick="document.bgColor='#00cc00'; alert('Correct! Good job :)')">False</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tasks'>
    <div class='container'>
      <h5>Question Three</h5>
      <h6>3) Ozone is "good" in the upper atmosphere but "bad" in the
            lower.</h6>
      <button onclick="document.bgColor='Green'; alert('Correct! Good job :)')">True</button>
      <button onclick="document.bgColor='#ff3300'; alert('Wrong! Unlucky. Try again :(')">
        False</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Many Thanks

James

Comment: Your question please??

Comment: First separate your CSS from the HTML. And my advise is to learn JQuery  (the easiest library for DOM manipulation - my opinion)

Comment: how can i make an image appear when the user clicks a button? @praguan

Comment: Just a suggestion,  if your onclick function is written the way it is, anyone who knows how to open dev console is going to get your quiz 100% right.

Comment: yes i know but it isnt for publishing just a personal page @SatejS

Comment: Have a look into the jQuery UI Dialog box option. 

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Do you require pure Javascript or is jQuery allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with javascript

```
<button id="mybutton" onclick="showButton()">Show Image </button>
```

```
function showButton(){
  image = document.getElementById('nameOfImageHere');
  image.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Ensure that it is previous display=none;

Comment: Yes you have to put display=none previously,  or you can have other button with the same function but change image.style.display = "none"

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

1 Method:
You may use jQuery Hide(), Show() function :

```
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#buttonIdShow").click(function(){
                    $("#Image").hide();
                });
                $("#buttonIdHide").click(function(){
                    $("#Image").show();
                });
            });
            </script>



        <img id="Image"/>               <!-Here is your image-->
    <button type="button" id="buttonIdShow">Show</button>  <!--Show button-->

    <button type="button" id="buttonIdHide">Hide</button> <!--Hide button-->
```

2 Method: jQuery Animate CSS display:

```
<script>
$("#yourButton1Id").click(function(){
  $("#ImageId").css("display","block");
});

$("#yourButton2Id").click(function(){
  $("#ImageId").css("display","none");
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: @james_nika if my solution is helped, pls mark up my solution, Thanx ;)